# Extract nested fields in sql using REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am using Google Big Query and querying 
Sample Records for column in table:

```
age=18;cntry=us;coid=9911718;csize=c;func=ops;gdr=f;grp=2099628;grp=85824;grp=1548357;grp=88799;grp=2059383;grp=1937629;ind=78;lang=en;mod=0;occ=511;optout=false;reg=21;s=0;seg=9001;seg=761;seg=541;seg=521;seg=1068;seg=557;seg=546;seg=514;seg=504;seg=183;seg=263;sub=0;tile=1;tile_p=1;title=ic;u=nql8uz5qrt8vcqh5tkcqq697
```

Query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(col,r'age=(\d+)') AS age,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col,r'cntry=(\d+)') AS country,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col,r'gdr=(\d+)') AS gender from table x
```

Result: `18 null    null`

I am getting only age value but other values as null. Any help will great on this.

Answer (score 0):

The `cntry` and `gdr` values are not numeric, they consist of letters.

You may use `\w+` matching 1 or more "word" chars, i.e. letters, digits and underscores:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(col,r'age=(\d+)') AS age,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col,r'cntry=(\w+)') AS country,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(col,r'gdr=(\w+)') AS gender from table x
```